# difference between .fdf and .h file in cpp project

Tags: c++

What is difference between **.fdf** and **.h** file in **cpp** project? 
I couldn't find a description of what a .fdf file is for? However, I tried to open and understand it myself. From that I observed that the contents are much similar to that of a .h file. And is also used in include statements just like .h files.

So, is .fdf file a special form of header file? Is it for a separate purpose?

As an example this is one of the function from .fdf file

```
nativeCode bool isEven
(
void
);
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on where you found it? In what project?

Comment: It just has a number of functions similar to i the one I posted above.

Comment: `.fdf` isn't part of normal c++ or any project I've heard of, so its likely either a special part of your build system or a component you're using (which you've not mentioned)

Comment: I mean, where you found the files?

Comment: File extensions don't have any inherent meaning. By **convention**, source files have the extension .cpp (or .C or .cxx or any of a handful of others), and header files have the extension .h (or .hxx or any of a handful of others). The extension .fdf is not one of the conventional extensions. It's part of whatever code base you're using, and should be documented there.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i found these files in the project I have just started working on.

Comment: What IDE and compiler are you using?  What platform?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows

Comment: https://fileinfo.com/extension/fdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably come across *Function Definition File* of *MDL* (Microstation Development Language) which is based on C.

*.fdf* are like *.h* but are used for all of the MDL functions that are not in the standard C.